# Unclear expression in Pimsleur 3 "here is a small gift"

Tags: meaning, usage, spelling

In the audio course Pimsleur Mandarin III an expression is taught which you can say when giving someone a gift. The expression itself is unclear to me, which one of these is it?

- yī diǎnr shǎo yì sī
- yī diǎnr xiǎo yì sī
- or something else?

Searching online I couldn't find any reference/usage of this expression. Is it a common expression to use?

Comment: 小意思 means a "small token" (of gratitude, etc.) Normally, you don't need to put a whole sentence around it. When you hand over a gift or someone makes a compliment about a gift you offered, you can use this expression to "downplay" the value, it conveys the notion of politeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character before 意思 should be 小. Notice that 小 has a connotation of size that 少 lacks; 少 is an indication of quantity. Moreover, 小意思 readily appears in dictionaries; 少意思 does not.

Otherwise, the overall construction (一点儿小意思) makes sense to me, and does appear in some online results. For example, [Zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net/c/f/6d/109873.htm) gives:

> 这是俺们家乡特产,你一定要收下,只是一点小意思

There is no 儿 affixed to the 点, but to the best of my knowledge, this discrepancy is not important.